# Need to know how to read html file with swift Playgrounds app for iPad

Tags: html, swift, swift-playground

I found a code to read html files with swift playground for ipad. But nothing showed up in the App Preview and I got error message : Cannot convert value of type ‘URL’ to expertes argument type ‘String’ . Can you help me because I don't know where the problem comes from. Here is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            WebView()
            
        }
        
        
        
    }
}

struct WebView:UIViewRepresentable{
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
          
        let htmlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "www")
        
        
        let htmlUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath)
        
     
        webView.loadFileURL(htmlUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlUrl.deletingLastPathComponent())
        
        return webView
    }
    
    
}
```

Need help to read html files with Swift Playgrounds for iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line `let htmlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "www")` with this `guard let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") else { return webView }`.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView:UIViewRepresentable{
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
    let webView = WKWebView()
      
    guard let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") else { return webView }
    
    
    let htmlUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath!)
    
 
    webView.loadFileURL(htmlUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlUrl.deletingLastPathComponent())
    
    return webView
}


}
```

Or You can change to this if you want.

```
    let htmlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html")
    webView.loadFileURL(htmlPath!, allowingReadAccessTo: htmlPath!.deletingLastPathComponent())
```